# Algebraizable is stable under extension.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism of noetherian schemes $f:X\to Y$, let $\hat{X}, \hat{Y}$ be their corresponding formal schemes. A coherent sheaf $E$ on $\hat{X}$ with support proper over $\hat{Y}$ is algebraizable if it’s of the form $\hat{F}$ for some coherent sheaf on $X$ with support proper over $Y$.

It’s said that algebraizable is stale under extension. In other words, if we have an exact sequence $0\to E\to F\to G\to 0$ of coherent sheaves on $\hat{X}$ with $E,G$ algebraizable, then $F$ is algebraizable. I am not sure how to proof this, but I have a naive idea. Denote $E=\hat{e}, G=\hat{g}$, we can have an extension $0\to e\to f\to g\to 0$. Then, since sheaves on formal schemes are defined under $I$-adic topology. By Artin-Rees, $0\to \hat{e}\to \hat{f} \to \hat{g} \to 0$ is exact, and we could deduce $F=\hat{f}$. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to show that their is a bijection $\operatorname{Ext}^1(e,g)=\operatorname{Ext}^1(E,G)$. What will probably work is expressing this as some coherent cohomology group on the support of $e$ and $f$, and then using a GAGA type theorem. [This argument should certainly work when $Y$ is a point, or when $Y$ itself is proper, I'm not sure if it can deal with the general case].

Comment: Why do we need to to have that bijection on $\operatorname{Ext}$ cohomology? Could you explain more?

Comment: @user45878-Could you explain more?

Comment: Those ext groups classify long exact sequences $0 \to E \to F \to G \to 0$ up to isomorphism. So if you start with an extensinsion $0 \to E \to F \to G \to 0 $ you want to prove that $F$ is also algebraizable, which is basically like saying that there is an extension $0 \to e \to f \to g \to 0$ corresponding to it. But you don't know that unless you have an equality of ext groups.

Comment: Right, thank you!